# Hexadecimal colors do not work on target style backgroundColor

Tags: javascript, html

1. I posted a previous question and someone responded with this code:

HTML:

```
<table class="bingo">
    <tr>
        <td id="square0"></td>
        <td id="square1"></td>
        <td id="square2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="square3"></td>
        <td id="square4"></td>
        <td id="square5"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="square6"></td>
        <td id="square7"></td>
        <td id="square8"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var toggleHighlight = function (e) {
   var bg = e.target.style.backgroundColor;
      if (bg == 'red') {
         e.target.style.backgroundColor = '';
       } else {
         e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';   
       }
   }

var prepareTable = function () {
   var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
       for (var i = 0 ; i < cells.length ; i++) {
         cells[i].onclick = function(event) {
           toggleHighlight(event);
          }
       }
 }

document.onload = prepareTable();
```

The code above is demonstrated here:
http://jsfiddle.net/nyzswnx2/47/

However, when I changed red to #cecece, and I was able to click on each cell which turns the cell from white to light gray. However, when I click the light gray cell again, it won't turn the cell from light gray to white. How do I fix that?

http://jsfiddle.net/RE006/nyzswnx2/82/

```
// e is parameter
var toggleHighlight = function (e) {
   var bg = e.target.style.backgroundColor;
    if (bg == "#cecece") {
      e.target.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
    } else {
      e.target.style.backgroundColor = "#cecece";   
    }
 }

/* getting a list from "td" will return a list, it is need for a loop to store the cells passes event as argument */
var prepareTable = function () {
  var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  for (var i = 0 ; i < cells.length ; i++) {
    cells[i].onclick = function(event) {
        toggleHighlight(event);
    }
   }
 }

//calls the function
document.onload = prepareTable();
```

Comment: Please do a  `console.log(bg)` to debug whether that color really comes back as `#cecece` after you set it

Comment: The color is stored as `rgb()` value. Either check for the rgb value, convert it to hex before your condition or use classes instead.

Comment: Hexadecimal: When I click on a white cell to make it light gray, under console: I get: an empty string, and the cell turns from white to light gray.  I click on the light gray cell, under console, I get: rgb (206, 206, 206), and the cell stays light gray.

Comment: RGB: When I click on a white cell to make it light gray, under console: I get: an empty string and the cell turns from white to light gray.  I click on the light gray cell, under console, I get: rgb (206, 206, 206), and the cell turns from light gray to white. I click on the cell again, the cell turns from white to light gray and console shows rgb(255,255,255).

So I just have to keep in mind that it does not recognize hexadecimals and  use rgb.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var bg = e.target.style.backgroundColor;
```

backgroundColor is being returned as rgb and not hex. The value of `bg` is  `rgb(206, 206, 206)`, not `#cecece`

You can try comparing the rgb string instead or converting the value to hex first.

```
if (bg == "rgb(206, 206, 206)") {
```